# Global trayicon and application icon in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I want a tray icon and application icon to be common for all forms in the application.
How can I achieve this.
For application icon:
I have added new icon in properties of application but still shows default icon in task bar.

For tray icon: I can do multiple functions for single form like added context menu, hide, open etc. But how to achieve this for all forms.

Can I create a global file that can be applied for all forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the icons in your code using the `Form.Load` event or the constructor.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // you could place this lines also in constructor
    // but make sure you place it after the InitializeComponent() call
    // bar is the name you defined while adding the resource
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.bar;

    // and for your tray icons
    this.notifyIcon1.Icon = Properties.Resources.bar;
}
```

You can do the same by using the forms designer and set the `Icon` property in the properties section of the form and the tray icon. In this case the designer will place pretty much the same code inside the designer generated file.

**Edit**

In order to prevent writing the same code again and again, you can write your own `Form` base class and set the icon in the constructor. Then you let all your `Forms` derive from that base class.

```
// File: MyFormBase.cs
public partial class MyFormBase : Form
{
    public MyFormBase()
        : base()
    {
        Icon = Properties.Resources.bar;
    }
}

// In your Form file:
public partial class MyForm : MyFormBase
{
    // ...
}
```

You will have to built the project to use the forms designer again after changing base class from `From` to `MyFormBase`.

Comment: I can do it for a single form but there will be different forms in an application right. I cant write same code for each and every form. So what is the solution?